Tensor Cores on NVIDIA GPU for CNN Model Inference
I was looking to leverage the tensor cores on my GPU for executing some CNN model inferences on it. Do frameworks like Pytorch or Tensorflow or MXNet or any of the frameworks for that matter, support inferencing on the tensor cores?
I've heard that tensor cores can be used for training purpose as Pytorch has an in-built support for it. Not sure if the same can be done for inferencing.

All frameworks can use tensor cores assuming 1. your GPU has tensor cores and 2. your model can actually take advantage of tensor cores (using mixed precision, all matmul sizes are a multiple of 8, etc).
For pytorch, you can read more here

So I'd been working around with CUDA + Tensor Cores for CNN based models. In pytorch there isn't apparently a way to toggle off CUDA cores and only run inference on Tensor Cores alone, is it? Also, I tried bloating the CUDA cores with a lot of workload so that it naturally pushes the work onto tensor cores, but that doesn't seem to be a good way of doing it.

I think you fundamentally misunderstand what a tensor core is. Tensor cores computes D=A*B+C where A, B are fp16 and A,B,C dimensions are a multiple of 8. Not all operations are applicable to this, which is why GPUs have vastly more CUDA cores compared to tensor cores (roughly 32x for modern GPUs). You can't "toggle off" CUDA cores. That is a nonsensical statement. You need both.
